# iPhone: How to access NSMutableArray two dimensional setting?

Tags: iphone

I am using insertObject for NSMutableArray for storing values into two dimensional array like below for example.

```
[mutableArrayPtr insertObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:firstData, secondData,nil] atIndex:index];
```

I think, it is correct way of storing values in two dimensional array in Obj C.

I want to access it at later point of time. How can i do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The way you are doing it is perfectly fine.* `NSArray`'s don't have native two dimensional syntax like primitive arrays (`int[][]`, `double[][]`, etc.) in C do. So instead, you must nest them using an array of arrays. Here's an example of how to do that:

```
NSString *hello = @"Hello World";
NSMutableArray *insideArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:hello,nil];
NSMutableArray *outsideArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[outsideArray addObject:insideArray];
// Then access it by:
NSString *retrieveString = [[outsideArray objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0];
```

To access your array at a later point in time, you would do something like:

```
NSArray* innerArray = [mutableArrayPtr objectAtIndex:0];
NSObject* someObject = [innerArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Of course, change `0` to whatever index you actually need to retrieve.

---

**EDIT**:

**Q:** *Is it "initWithObjects" (or) "insertObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:imagePtrData,urlInStr,nil]" for two dimension?*

**A:** `initWithObjects` and `insertObject` would both allow you to create two dimensional arrays. For example you could do:

```
NSMutableArray* arrayOne = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSArray initWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", @"Three", nil], [NSArray initWithObjects:[@"Four", @"Five", @"Six", nil], nil];
// NOTE: You need to release the above array somewhere in your code to prevent a memory leak.
```

or:

```
NSMutableArray* arrayTwo = [NSMutableArray array];
[arrayTwo insertObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", @"Three", nil] atIndex:0];
```

Comment: Is it "initWithObjects" (or) "insertObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:imagePtrData,urlInStr,nil]" for two dimension?

Comment: Since when CFArray has a native 2D syntax? The built-in C array type `T[n]` isn't the same as CFArray.

Comment: @KennyTM: Thanks for the tip, and I see you're correct! I have updated the answer to reflect this tidbit. Thanks again, I learn something new everyday.

Comment: Actually C does not have `int[m,n]` (that would be C#). Multidimensional array in C is defined as `int a[m][n]` and used as `a[1][2]`.

Comment: @KennyTM: Double Fail! Updated again.